# Make a snapshot of working directory with git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-stash

I sometimes need to make a snapshot of the current (possibly dirty) working directory. `git stash save -u` is very similar to what I need but there are two problems:

1. I want my working directory to stay in the same state (keep untracked files untracked)
2. In case I need to come back to the saved state (maybe a month later), it would not be easy to `git stash apply` because I first need to find the state before `git stash`.

I currently have the following sequence of commands that works for me but I would like to know if there is a more elegant way of doing it.

```
# on branch master
git add .
git commit -m "Temporary commit on the original branch"
git checkout -b snapshot_of_master_yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss HEAD~
git merge master
git checkout master
git reset HEAD^
```

---

Thank you everyone for the answers and explanations! I am going to do something like this mostly based on @XavierGuihot's answer

```
git stash -u # -u to include untracked files
git checkout -b snapshot_of_master_yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss
git stash apply
git add --all
git commit -m "Snapshot"
git checkout master
git stash pop --index # --index to recover the state of indexed files
```

Comment: Do you prefer not to commit on the master?

Comment: @XavierGuihot yes the commit on the master is undone in the last line.

Comment: Just thought about this and tried it out and I agree with the stash method shown above, it seems to do everything needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can stash your changes, create a new branch, apply your changes, perform the commit only on the new branch and then checkout master again before finally applying your changes again.

```
git stash
git checkout -b snapshot_of_master_yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss
git stash apply
git add --all
git commit -m "Snapshot"
git checkout master
git stash pop
```

Comment: Do you need `git stash pop` after `git checkout master`?

Comment: Yes indeed! Fixing the answer

Comment: Digging a little bit more, I found [this article](https://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/git-stash-pop-considered-harmful/) in which I discovered that `git stash branch <branch_name>` can replace `git checkout -b <branch_name>` + `git stash apply`. And which also provides a nice shell alias to do exactly what you need.

Comment: `git stash branch` seems to also drop the stash which does not allow me to do `git stash pop` at the end

Comment: This is what I end up doing

    git stash
    git checkout -b snapshot_of_master_yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss
    git stash apply
    git add --all
    git commit -m "Snapshot"
    git checkout master
    git stash pop --index

Comment: You're right, the `git stash branch` unfortunatly does pop the stash.

Answer (score 4):

Most efficient with no worktree churn is to do it directly with core commands, assuming you don't have any inflight merge conflicts or intent-to-add markers in the index it's

```
statenow=`git write-tree`
stashedindex=`git commit-tree -p @ -m "index snap" $statenow`
git add -f .
git tag snap-`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H.%M.%S` \
            $(git commit-tree -p @ -p $stashedindex \
                    -m "worktree snap" \
                    $(git write-tree)
            )
git read-tree $statenow
```

but the  simplest way if you don't care about ignored files or no-effect worktree churn will be

```
git stash -a -u
git tag snap-`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H.%M.%S stash
git stash pop
```

then for either, to recover the state you do e.g.

```
git clean -dfx
git checkout snap-2018-02-18T14.19.15           # to move HEAD + worktree there
# or
git read-tree -um @ snap-2018-02-18T14.19.15    # just the worktree

git read-tree @ snap-2018-02-18T14.19.15^2      # then restore the index
```

Comment: Note that `git stash save -u` doesn't add ignored files, and therefore doesn't use `git clean -x`; your `git add -f .` here does add ignored files so your use of `-x` here would be appropriate. You might want to make sure you are at the top of the tree, though, or use `git add -f $(git rev-parse --show-top-level)` or similar to make sure you aren't working only with subdirectories.

Comment: Oh, and: you don't want `git stash save -a -u`, the later `-u` will override the `-a` (at least in older versions of `git stash`, I have not checked to see if newer ones detect the conflicting options).

Answer (score 2):

#### TL;DR

Use [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48857426/1256452), which he wrote while I was away from the keyboard between stages of writing the long answer below.

#### Long

Before you settle on any one answer to this question (see [jthill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48857426/1256452) for the set I think are in some sense "the best"), consider this:  Whenever you have a state that isn't just "everything tracked in the work-tree exactly matches `HEAD`", there are *three* versions of each file to worry about.

That is, when you first run:

```
git clone <url>
```

or, from a totally clean (no untracked files, no modified files, etc.) state do:

```
git checkout <somebranch>
```

you *start out with* three copies of each file, such as `README` and `Makefile` and so on, available right now:

- One in `HEAD` (the tip commit of whichever branch you have checked out): this one is read-only and of course matches the one in `HEAD`, because it *is* the one in `HEAD`.  This `HEAD:README` file is stored in the special Git-only format that Git uses.  (Use `git show HEAD:README` to see it.)
- One in the *index*.  The index is where you will build your next commit, but right now, it just contains a copy of everything that is in the *current* commit.  So `:0:README`—you can use `git show :0:README` to see this copy—exactly matches `HEAD:README`.  This extra copy is also stored in the special Git-only format, which means it takes essentially no space at all.  The difference between `:0:README` and `HEAD:README` is that you can *overwrite* this one: `git add README` copies the work-tree `README` into `:0:README`, for instance.  (The copy you make here will take some space, but will then be what goes into the next `git commit`, after which they'll share that frozen / read-only version, until you copy yet another one in.)
- The last copy of each file, such as `README`, is in the work-tree.  This file is in its normal everyday format, so that all programs can read and write it.  There's no need to view it with `git show` because it's just a normal file!

Initially, *all three versions match*, and there are no untracked files.

So:

> I sometimes need to make a snapshot of the current (possibly dirty) working directory.

for every file with path *`P`* except for *untracked* files, we have:

- the version of *`P`* that is in the HEAD commit: you never need to save this one, as it's already saved, permanently, by being in a commit;
- the version of *`P`* that is in the index: do you want to save this one?; and
- the version of *`P`* that is in the work-tree: you no doubt do want to save this one.

That also leaves the question of what to do with the *untracked* files.

Let's note here that an untracked file is simply a file in the work-tree that does not exist in the index.  (This includes files that are in `HEAD` but that you carefully *removed from* the index—they're currently untracked, as long as the work-tree version of that file exists.)

> `git stash save -u` is very similar to what I need ...

That is a good clue, because `git stash save -u` saves:

- the current index (as one commit);
- the current work-tree (as another commit, tracked files only); and
- the untracked files (as a third commit).  Note that the third commit omits files that are untracked-and-ignored (there is no such thing a as a file that is both tracked and ignored; "ignored" applies only to files that are already untracked).  If you want the ignored files as well you must use `-a` instead of `-u` here.

> ... but there are two problems: [1. `git stash -u` removes the untracked files after committing them, and 2. `git stash -u` makes it rather hard to un-stash again later]

Note that `git stash -u` simply runs `git clean` to remove the untracked files.  You would have to do a `git reset --hard && git clean -df` to get back to the state to unstash (but see the problem case I mention below).

Now, the main problem with making a commit—*any* commit—is that you do it by copying files into the index.  But we just noted that there could be index versions of various files, like `:0:README` and `:0:path/to/important.data`, that differ from their `HEAD:` counterparts *and* from their work-tree counterparts.  If you do anything to save the work-tree counterparts, you must do it by overwriting the index copy!

*If this is okay*, you could possibly have a path forward that's less complicated than using `git stash` or equivalent.  But you still have a problem with untracked files!  If it's not OK, you must save the index first, just like `git stash` does, in which case you might want to just use `git stash`.

We already noted, above, that an untracked file is a file that's in the work-tree—has some path *U*—that is not also in the index: there's no `:0:U`.  This creates something of a problem: to save those files, we have to copy them into the index.  This, of course, destroys (overwrites) anything we carefully staged that's different from both `HEAD` and work-tree version.  This is where the all the complications come from.

If you do want to preserve the index state for any reason, *and* the index state records which files should be tracked and untracked later, then we have our solution (which is jthill's solution as well), which is much like `git stash`, but slightly modified:

- Write out the current index state: `git write-tree`.
- Use the result to make a commit (permanent until it has no name, when it can be garbage collected): `git commit-tree`.  This commit can have the current commit (`HEAD` or `@`) as its parent, although that's not actually required.
- Add to the index all the untracked files (possibly including ignored files): `git add -A`, or `git add -f -A`, etc., depending on what precisely you want in this second commit.
- Write this updated index, then use the result to make a second commit whose parent is the saved index state, and give this second commit a name to make it permanent.  (In jthill's answer, just as `git stash` does, he has the second commit store both commits as parents, with the index commit as the second parent of the second commit.  That forces us to use the suffix `^2` notation later, which has the advantage that it works with the `git stash` script.)

Having written all of these out, we must immediately put the index back into its original state—the one we saved as the first step.  Otherwise all the previously-untracked files are now tracked files!

To restore one of these things, we have the same problem you have already with `git stash save -u`: the files in the second commit we made (to hold the untracked files) are going to become, at least temporarily, *tracked* files.  If there are files with those same names in the work-tree right now, Git will be very reluctant to overwrite them—so we need a `git clean -df` or `git clean -dfx` to destroy them.  There's a bit of a problem here because this will *also* remove files that *aren't* in that second commit: for instance, suppose when you saved everything, there was an untracked file named `important-1` but nothing named `important-2`.  *Now* there's an `important-2`.

If you just naively run `git clean -df` or `git clean -dfx` right now, Git will remove *both* of these untracked `important-*` files.  Then we'll instruct Git to extract, from the second commit, all the files, including the previously-untracked `important-1`.  Git will copy the file into both the index and the work-tree.  Since there is no saved `important-2`, Git *won't* copy that file.

This is the rather large defect to using:

```
git clean -dfx
git checkout snap-2018-02-18T14.19.15
```

and is why:

```
git read-tree -um @ snap-2018-02-18T14.19.15
git read-tree @ snap-2018-02-18T14.19.15^2
```

is better.  The first step, `git read-tree -um @ snap-...`, does a merge-and-update to bring in the second commit we made (holding all the work-tree state) into the index and update the work-tree.  That way `important-2` won't be destroyed.

The second step is needed to fix up the index afterward, because reading all those untracked files from the second commit causes them to become *tracked* files.  We'd like to restore the index to the way it was when we made the snapshot, or at least, pull *out* of the index any files that are in it now that should not be in it.

We have exactly that index state: it's in the *first* commit we made, which is `snap-...^2` (the second parent of the snapshot or the stash).  We can either read that directly into the index:

```
git read-tree snap-2018-02-18T14.19.15^2
```

(note the lack of `@` / `HEAD` here), or do a two-tree merge to leave modifications we've made to the index in place where possible:

```
git read-tree @ snap-2018-02-18T14.19.15^2
```

Note that we could, instead, just reset the index to match the commit you are currently on:

```
git reset HEAD
```

or perhaps reset it to the parent of the saved first commit:

```
git read-tree snap-2018-02-18T14.19.15^1
```

if you didn't really want to save the index state.  Either way, the untracked files are once again untracked, now that they're no longer in the index.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! The difference between the three versions are a lot more clear to me. In the snapshot, I don't need to distinguish the version in the index and the work-tree so I think I am going to use `git stash`.

Answer (score 2):

Another clean and simple approach. Even no branch changing nor `stash` needed:

```
git commit
git branch name-of-my-snapshot-branch
git reset HEAD^
```

With the `commit` just commit everything you want to snapshot, in whichever way you prefer to do this.

The `reset` points your branch to the former commit and so you are back to where you started.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @XavierGuihot's answer and @RyotaTomioka's edit, you can use the following git alias:

```
snapshot = "!f() { CURRENT_BRANCH=`git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` && git stash -uq && git switch -q -c snapshot_`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`_$1 && git stash apply -q && git add --all && git commit -q -m "Snapshot" && git switch -q $CURRENT_BRANCH && git stash pop -q --index && echo "created branch snapshot_`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`_$1 containing the current working tree [including untracked files]";}; f"
```

If you copy this to your `.gitconfig` under `[alias]` you can use

```
git snapshot MYTEXT
```

to create a new branch `snapshot_yyyy-mm-dd_HH-MM-SS_MYTEXT` that contains the current working tree (including untracked files) but keeps the current state (branch, status of files: staged/unstaged) intact.